# Remove leading zeros in powershell

Tags: powershell, trim

I have several strings and try to remove the leading zeros for them. I know I can use `TrimStart()` but it's wrong if all numbers are zero.

```
$Test = "00000.22"
$Test = $Test.trimstart('0')
```

The result is .22 and what I expect is 0.22. How can I achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use type conversion to decimal

```
$Test = "00000.22"
[decimal]$Test
```

Answer (score 7):

A purely *textual* solution is to use the [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operator with a *regular expression*:

```sh
PS> '00000.22' -replace '^0+', '0' 
0.22
```

`^0+` matches one or more (`+`) zeros at the start (`^`) of the string and replaces them with a *single* zero.

If you also want to make sure that numbers with an integral part that isn't `0` and/or without a fractional part are properly handled, use
`-replace '^0+(?=[^.])'` (note the absence of a substitution operand, which effectively *removes* what gets matched):

```sh
PS> ('00000.22', '0000', '00001.22').ForEach({ $_ -replace '^0+(?=[^.])' })
0.22
0
1.22
```

Positive look-ahead assertion `(?=[^.])` effectively removes all leading zeros (`^0+`) as long as such a zero isn't followed by a literal `.` (`[^.]`).

<sup>If you *do* want something like `'00000.22'` to become just `'.22'`, i.e. if you want to drop the integral part if it happens to be `0`, the regex becomes simpler: `'^0+(?=.)'`</sup>

---

[gms0ulman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49117758/45375) is convenient and probably works fine in most cases, but there are *pitfalls*:

- You're changing the data type to `[decimal]`, and converting that back to a string *can result in a culture-specific representation where `.` is converted to `,`* (that said, PowerShell itself often applies the *invariant* culture, which *always* uses `.`); e.g.:

  ```sh
    # Cast to [decimal] using the German culture ('de')
    PS> [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'de'; [decimal] '0000.22'
    0,22  # !! Note the "," instead of "."
  ```
- Even though unlikely with a high-precision data type such as `[decimal]`, rounding errors *are* possible:

  ```sh
    PS> [decimal] '00.99999999999999999999999999999'
    1.0000000000000000000000000000 # !! rounding occurred
  ```